# saving arabic data as csv file

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, arabic

Please I have a DataFrame which contains arabic data , I want to save it as csv file ( or .text),  but when I try I have a problem with encoding arabic data .
I  read my data like this : `cname=readLines('C:/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/Bureau/arabic data R/cnn-arabic-utf8/cnn-arabic-utf8/spt/sportcnnAr08sport (2).html.txt',encoding='UTF-8')`

I try to save it with different ways :

```
con<-file('C:/Users/ahmed/Desktop/test.csv',encoding="utf8")
write.csv(clust.df ,file=con)
```

`save(clust.df , file = "C:/Users/ahmed/Desktop/clust.txt")`

```
write.csv(clust.df, file = "C:/Users/ahmed/Desktop/clust.txt",fileEncoding='UTF-8')
```

the output is always :

```
"<U+0623><U+062D><U+0627><U+0644><U+062A>",1
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried the `writeLines` function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
testfile <- "C:/Users/ahmed/Desktop/test.csv"
log <- function(msg="") {
  con <- file(testfile, "a")
  tryCatch({
    cat(iconv(msg, to="UTF-8"), file=con, sep="\n")
  },
  finally = {
    close(con)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure 
But i am 99% sure :) that CSV file or txt file don't retain character encoding.
So i will suggest that try with Excel File (just to test if excel is showing correct data or not)

Comment: am facing the same issue but no luck with any remedy. Any solution for this?